# Product Rule: Derivative with an indicator function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I was wondering what the derivative (gradient) looks like for a function with a product that includes an indicator function. For instance, I have the pdf of some distribution can be written as:

$f(x) = af_1(x)1_{[x \le \alpha]} + bf_2(x)1_{[x > \alpha]}$

I'm trying to understand what the gradient/derivative of this function is with respect to $\alpha$. And from there, what $\cfrac{\partial log(f(x))}{\partial \alpha}$ looks like. My initial thought is the gradient is 0 if the pdfs $f_1(x), f_2(x)$ don't depend on $\alpha$ is this true? Thanks

Comment: The derivative is $0$ at all points except $\alpha =x$. At this point the derivative does not exist.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks. Does this change if there is a condition such that $af_1(\alpha) = bf_2(\alpha)$?  Then a and b depend on $\alpha$ as well.